# RadComboBox doesn't have default DropDownList feature

Tags: asp.net, telerik

When I use asp DropDownList and populate it with some items (a, ab, abc, b, ba etc) I click to open drop down list and type 'a' on keyboard selection goes to first item that begins with 'a' and when I type 'ab' it goes to 'ab'.
But in telerik RadComboBox when I type 'ab' it goes to the first item that begins with 'b' and  not to 'ab'.
Is it possible to fix this somehow on RadComboBox?

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcb_Products" runat="server" DataTextField="ProductName" DataValueField="ProductId"
                                                    Width="100%" Skin="Windows7">
                                                </telerik:RadComboBox>

...
this.rcb_Products.DataSource = productsList;
                this.rcb_Products.DataTextField = "Text";
                this.rcb_Products.DataValueField = "Value";
                this.rcb_Products.DataBind();
...
```

Comment: can you show me your rad combo box design structure and binding ??

Comment: I have updated question with code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please write like this:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcb_Products" runat="server" DataTextField="ProductName" DataValueField="ProductId"
                                                    Width="100%" Skin="Windows7" Filter="StartsWith">
                                                </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Only add this to your design view:

**Filter="StartsWith"**

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for but I like this :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add these properties to your RadComboBox:

AllowCustomText="True" MarkFirstMatch="True"